# Is there a way to use a DbSet in another model with additional properties?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, datagrid, entity-framework-core

In my UWP application I have a model called Product.cs:

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double PricePerPiece { get; set; }
    public double PricePerKilogram { get; set; }
    public double Iva { get; set; }
    public double ContainerPrice { get; set; }
    public string ContainerType { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public bool Equals(Product otherProduct)
    {
        return
            this.ProductName == otherProduct.ProductName &&
            this.PricePerPiece == otherProduct.PricePerPiece &&
            this.PricePerKilogram == otherProduct.PricePerKilogram &&
            this.Iva == otherProduct.Iva &&
            this.ContainerPrice == otherProduct.ContainerPrice &&
            this.ContainerType == otherProduct.ContainerType;
    }
}
```

I created a DbSet based on this model and used it as ItemSource for a DataGrid in a View.

```
public class MarketContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new DbContext.
    /// </summary>
    public MarketContext(DbContextOptions<MarketContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customers DbSet.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the products DbSet.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to have another DataGrid in a different View that display the ProductName, the PricePerPiece but also the quantity and a total price (quantity * PricePerPiece). The quantity of each product is inserted by the user while the total price column has to update automatically its content.
The solution that I tried is to create another model called LineProduct.cs with the Quantity and TotalPrice properties but I don't know how to associate them with the products stored in the database and display all these four columns in a single DataGrid.

```
public class LineProduct
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double PricePerPiece { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public Guid LineProductId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

ProductName and PricePerPiece properties in the LineProduct class must be retrive the content from the Products table I created in the database.
The goal is to allow the user to add, update or delete products in a view (this part works fine) and make calculation with this products in another view and eventually save it in the database with a DbSet.

Comment: Can you please show us the code you are mentioning in your question

Comment: I just edited the question. Thanks

Comment: To "feed" the second view's DataGrid you need a query that will return the data for you (you can use your type LineProduct). Then in the View the user will enter the quantity and it's the View's responsibility to do the calculation and update itself (price * qty). If later you want to save this modification, you can use the same model LineProduct to post the changes back to the server.

Comment: The "TotalPrice" is just a display field, it's not going to be stored in the database. With the `PricePerPiece` + the `Quantity` you can always calculate again the total price.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need

[MVC Pattern](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc)

> MVC is a design pattern used to decouple user-interface (view), data (model), and application logic (controller). This pattern helps to achieve separation of concerns.

You already have your model, the viewmodel is a class with the properties you need for the ui. The controller is were you make the calculations and also map between the model and viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a one-to-many relation between `LineProduct` and `Product`.

1. The `LineProduct` model -

```
public class LineProduct
{
    public Guid LineProductId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    public string ProductName 
    {
        get { return this.Product != null ? this.Product.ProductName : null; }
    }
    public double PricePerPiece 
    { 
        get { return this.Product != null ? this.Product.PricePerPiece : 0; } 
    }        
    public double TotalPrice 
    { 
        get { return this.Quantity * this.PricePerPiece; } 
    }

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

2. Configure the relationship in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LineProduct>(e =>
    {
        e.HasKey(p => p.LineProductId);
        e.HasOne(p => p.Product)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);
    });
}
```

3. Add a `DbSet` for `LineProduct` in your `DbContext` -

```
public DbSet<LineProduct> LineProducts { get; set; }
```

4. Query for `LineProduct` so that it includes the related `Product` -

```
var list = myDbContext.LineProducts.Include(p=> p.Product).ToList();
```

Comment: I did as you told me but the LineProduct table remains empty. If I add a product in the Product table, nothing happens in the LineProduct table so when query its data, the DataGrid remain empty just like the table (for debug purpose I check the tables and their content with a DB browser).

Comment: @Filiberto I think I misunderstood the purpose or usage of `LineProduct`. A `LineProduct` object has its own data, like `Quantity`, so creating a product will definitely not create a `LineProduct` for you. `LineProduct` is a different entity whose data will be stored in a different table.

Comment: I probably mistook the question. What I would like is another DataGrid with the various products from the DbSet<Product> Products, but also a column with quantity (editable by the user) and a column with total price (quantity * PricePerPiece). The problem is that I could not add these two columns as they are not linked to any DataSource. 
Furthermore, each row in this new DataGrid with the product name, price, quantity and total price must be saved in another table in the database for any future changes. **LineProduct** was just my attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @Filiberto I'm not familiar with UWP DataGrid, but the `DataSource` that you used to display the product grid will not work here. You have to create a new table `LineProduct` with `Id`, `Quantity` and `ProductId` column where `ProductId` will be a foreign-key to the `Product` table. Then you have to use the query I mentioned in the answer. It will give you a list of `LineProduct` entity with the related `Product` entity. You have create your `DataSource` against this query.